# Spring Data MongoDB 4.0 transactions support

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

MongoDB 4.0 are going to introduce [transactions](https://www.mongodb.com/transactions) support with ACID guarantees.

Does Spring Data MongoDB already supports the transactions in MongoDB and if no, when this awesome feature will be available. I really need it, taking into account the following issue - [MongoDB schema design in order to support application horizontal scaling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50842214/mongodb-schema-design-in-order-to-support-application-horizontal-scaling)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does Spring Data MongoDB already supports the transactions in MongoDB

Spring Data Lovelace M3 (2.1.0.M3) supports synchronous transaction for MongoDB v4.0, released on May 17th 2018. See also [Spring Data Lovelace M3 release notes](https://spring.io/blog/2018/05/17/spring-data-lovelace-m3-released).

Example from [Spring Data docs: MongoDB transactions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/2.1.0.M3/reference/html/#mongo.transactions)

```
ClientSession session = client.startSession(options);                   

template.withSession(session)
    .execute(action -> {
        session.startTransaction();                                     
        try {

            Step step = // ...;
            action.insert(step);
            process(step);
            action.update(Step.class).apply(Update.set("state", // ...
            session.commitTransaction();                                
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            session.abortTransaction();                                 
        }
    }, ClientSession::close)                                            
    .subscribe();
```

See also related: [DATAMONGO-1920](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1920) and [DATAMONGO-1970](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1970)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you have an idea when it will be released and included into some Spring Boot RELEASE ?

Comment: @WanBachtiar Does Spring Data supports transaction support for mongodb that is older than version 4.0.

Comment: @Desert no on the database level. You _may_ be able to use software level transactions with Spring [Transaction Management](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#transaction) I would just recommend to upgrade to 4.0 to simplify it if you're able to upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer the answer that I recently answered on another thread, I hope that will be helpful to you.

But that is for reactive style Spring Boot and MongoDB setup

The link is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61676211/2600196)