# Calling methods in two different ReactiveMongoRepository's in a transaction using Spring Data MongoDB?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb-reactive

When using the reactive programming model with Spring Data MongoDB it's possible to execute transactions like this:

```java
Mono<DeleteResult> result = template.inTransaction()                                      
    .execute(action -> action.remove(query(where("id").is("step-1")), Step.class));
```

But Spring Data MongoDB also has support for "reactive repositories", for example:

```java
public interface PersonRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<Person, String>

  Flux<Person> findByLocationNear(Point location, Distance distance);
}
```

and

```java
public interface CarRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<Car, String>

  Flux<Car> findByYear(int year);
}
```

My question is, given that you have `ReactiveMongoRepository`'s, can you somehow leverage MongoDB transactions and e.g. insert both a `Person` and `Car` in the same transaction (using `PersonRepository` and `CarRepository` in the case)? If so, how do you do this?

Comment: any help on this mate? @Johan

Comment: Sorry but I don't recall that I found a solution to it.

Comment: luckily after messaging you I figured that out, will shortly share that with you

Comment: see the answer below

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had also been trying hard to find solution for the **Transactional** support in Reactive style of Mongo DB & Spring Boot

But luckily I figured it myself. Though few of the things from google were also helpful but those were non reactive.

**Important Note** - For Spring boot 2.2.x it works well, but with spring boot 2.3.x it has some other issues, it has internal re-write & changes all together

- You need to use ***ReactiveMongoTransactionManager*** along with ***ReactiveMongoDatabaseFactory***, most of the details at the end, also sharing the code repo for the same
- ***For getting the mongo db to support the Transactions we need to make sure that the DB should be running in replica mode***.

  **Why we need that? Because you will get some error like this otherwise:-**

  *Sessions are not supported by the MongoDB cluster to which this client is connected*

The instructions for the same are below:-

1. run the docker-compose based mongo db server using docker-compose.yml as shared below:-

```
version: "3"
services:
    mongo:
        hostname: mongo
        container_name: localmongo_docker
        image: mongo
        expose:
          - 27017
        ports:
          - 27017:27017
        restart: always
        entrypoint: [ "/usr/bin/mongod", "--bind_ip_all", "--replSet", "rs0" ]
        volumes:
          - ./mongodata:/data/db # need to create a docker volume named as mongodata first
```

2. After the image comes up, execute the command(here **localmongo_docker** is the name of the container):-

```
docker exec -it localmongo_docker mongo
```

3. Copy and paste the command below and execute that

```
rs.initiate(
   {
     _id : 'rs0',
     members: [
       { _id : 0, host : "mongo:27017" }
     ]
   }
 )
```

4. And then exit the execution by entering **exit**

***Important*** - The code repo can be found here on my github - https://github.com/krnbr/mongo-spring-boot-template

Important notes for the code are as below:-

- **MongoConfiguration** class in the **config** package is the important part to make the transactions working, link to the configuration class is [here](https://github.com/krnbr/mongo-spring-boot-template/blob/master/src/main/java/in/neuw/example/config/MongoConfiguration.java)
- Main part is the **Bean**

  ```
   @Bean
   ReactiveMongoTransactionManager transactionManager(ReactiveMongoDatabaseFactory dbFactory) {
       return new ReactiveMongoTransactionManager(dbFactory);
   }
  ```
- For checking the working of the code's Transactional requirement you may go through the class UserService in service package [here](https://github.com/krnbr/mongo-spring-boot-template/blob/master/src/main/java/in/neuw/example/service/UserService.java)

Code shared in case the links do not work for someone:-

**The Configuration and inside the Beans**

```
@Configuration
public class MongoConfiguration extends AbstractMongoClientConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private MongoProperties mongoProperties;

    @Bean
    ReactiveMongoTransactionManager transactionManager(ReactiveMongoDatabaseFactory dbFactory) {
        return new ReactiveMongoTransactionManager(dbFactory);
    }

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return mongoProperties.getDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public MongoClient mongoClient() {
        return MongoClients.create(mongoProperties.getUri());
    }
}
```

**application.properties** (related to mongo db)

```
spring.data.mongodb.database=mongo
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://localhost:27017/mongo?replicaSet=rs0
```

**Document Classes**

**Role Class**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Accessors(chain = true)
@Document(collection = "roles")
@TypeAlias("role")
public class Role implements Persistable<String> {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Field("role_name")
    @Indexed(unique = true)
    private String role;

    @CreatedDate
    private ZonedDateTime created;

    @LastModifiedDate
    private ZonedDateTime updated;

    private Boolean deleted;

    private Boolean enabled;

    @Override
    @JsonIgnore
    public boolean isNew() {
        if(getCreated() == null)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

**User Class**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Accessors(chain = true)
@Document(collection = "users")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@TypeAlias("user")
public class User implements Persistable<String> {

    @Id()
    private String id;

    @Field("username")
    @Indexed(unique = true)
    @JsonProperty("username")
    private String userName;

    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    private String password;

    @CreatedDate
    private ZonedDateTime created;

    @LastModifiedDate
    private ZonedDateTime updated;

    private Boolean deleted;

    private Boolean enabled;

    @DBRef(lazy = true)
    @JsonProperty("roles")
    private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList();

    @Override
    @JsonIgnore
    public boolean isNew() {
        if(getCreated() == null)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

**UserProfile Class**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Accessors(chain = true)
@Document(collection = "user_profiles")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@TypeAlias("user_profile")
public class UserProfile implements Persistable<String> {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Indexed(unique = true)
    private String mobile;

    @Indexed(unique = true)
    private String email;

    private String address;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    @DBRef
    private User user;

    @CreatedDate
    private ZonedDateTime created;

    @LastModifiedDate
    private ZonedDateTime updated;

    private Boolean deleted;

    private Boolean enabled;

    @Override
    @JsonIgnore
    public boolean isNew() {
        if(getCreated() == null)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

}
```

**ReactiveMongoRepository Interface(s)**

**RoleRepository**

```
public interface RoleRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<Role, String> {

    Mono<Role> findByRole(String role);

    Flux<Role> findAllByRoleIn(List<String> roles);

}
```

**UserRepository**

```
public interface UserRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<User, String> {

    Mono<User> findByUserName(String userName);

}
```

**UserProfileRepository**

```
public interface UserProfileRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<UserProfile, String> {
}
```

**The User Service Class** Need to create your own RuntimeException Class here, here it is AppRuntimeException Class, I had been using

```
@Slf4j
@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private UserProfileRepository userProfileRepository;

    @Transactional
    public Mono<UserProfile> saveUserAndItsProfile(final UserRequest userRequest) {

        Mono<Role> roleMono = roleRepository.findByRole("USER");

        Mono<User> userMono = roleMono.flatMap(r -> {
            User user = new User()
                    .setUserName(userRequest.getUsername())
                    .setPassword(userRequest.getPassword());
            user.setRoles(Arrays.asList(r));
            return userRepository.save(user);
        }).onErrorResume(ex -> {
            log.error(ex.getMessage());
            if(ex instanceof DuplicateKeyException) {
                String errorMessage = "The user with the username '"+userRequest.getUsername()+"' already exists";
                log.error(errorMessage);
                return Mono.error(new AppRuntimeException(errorMessage, ErrorCodes.CONFLICT, ex));
            }
            return Mono.error(new AppRuntimeException(ex.getMessage(), ErrorCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, ex));
        });

        Mono<UserProfile> userProfileMono = userMono.flatMap(u -> {
            UserProfile userProfile = new UserProfile()
                    .setAddress(userRequest.getAddress())
                    .setEmail(userRequest.getEmail())
                    .setMobile(userRequest.getMobile())
                    .setUser(u);
            return userProfileRepository.save(userProfile);
        }).onErrorResume(ex -> {
            log.error(ex.getMessage());
            if(ex instanceof DuplicateKeyException) {
                String errorMessage = "The user with the profile mobile'"+userRequest.getMobile()+"' and/or - email '"+userRequest.getEmail()+"' already exists";
                log.error(errorMessage);
                return Mono.error(new AppRuntimeException(errorMessage, ErrorCodes.CONFLICT, ex));
            }
            return Mono.error(new AppRuntimeException(ex.getMessage(), ErrorCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, ex));
        });

        return userProfileMono;

    }

}
```

**Controller and the Model Class**

**UserRequest** Model Class

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Accessors(chain = true)
@Slf4j
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class UserRequest {

    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String mobile;
    private String email;
    private String address;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

}
```

**UserProfileApisController** class

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/apis/user/profile")
public class UserProfileApisController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @PostMapping
    public Mono<UserProfile> saveUserProfile(final @RequestBody UserRequest userRequest) {
        return userService.saveUserAndItsProfile(userRequest);
    }

}
```

Comment: @Johan I am still in the process of doing the editing. But please go through the details I shared in the answer

Comment: Thanks @kakabali, but could you please include the gist of your code examples here? I think this is custom for stackoverflow answers since remote links may cease to exist.

Answer (score 2):

Just an addition to the accepted answer regarding MongoDB replica set initialization.

1. If one needs a non-fixed port single replica set for testing they might use [the Testcontainers’ MongoDB Module](https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/mongodb/) that encapsulates such initialization:

```java
final MongoDBContainer mongoDBContainer = new MongoDBContainer("mongo:4.2.8");
```

We can start it via ‘mongoDBContainer.start()’ and stop it via try-with-resources or ‘mongoDBContainer.stop()’. [See more details on this module and Spring Data MongoDB here](https://dev.to/silaev/the-testcontainers-mongodb-module-and-spring-data-mongodb-in-action-53ng).

2. If one needs a non-fixed port multi-node replica set for testing complex production issues, they might use [this project](https://github.com/silaev/mongodb-replica-set), for example:

```java
try (
  //create a PSA mongoDbReplicaSet and auto-close it afterwards
  final MongoDbReplicaSet mongoDbReplicaSet = MongoDbReplicaSet.builder()
    //with 2 working nodes
    .replicaSetNumber(2)
    //with an arbiter node
    .addArbiter(true)
    //create a proxy for each node to simulate network partitioning
    .addToxiproxy(true)
    .build()
) {
  //start it
  mongoDbReplicaSet.start();
  assertNotNull(mongoDbReplicaSet.getReplicaSetUrl());
  //do some testing
}
```