# spring transactional in R2DBC mongo and postgresql

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc-postgresql

I've started working with Spring Webflux and project reactor. I'm struggling with "Transactional" concept.
I don't understand if @Transcational keyword is still valid on methods which performs operations on  ReactiveMongoRepository or PostgreSql repository (e.g. save, update, delete).

Actually I'm using built-in metods to ReactiveMongoRepository to perform save, delete etc. But what if e.g. save will fail and I'd like to be my changes reverted back. Should I put Transactional on method. Is it valid keyword in Spring Webflux with project reactor?
Thank you for help and clarification.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56360094/calling-methods-in-two-different-reactivemongorepositorys-in-a-transaction-usin